# How can I Recover deleted WhatsApp Images on Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, images

The day before yesterday I was browsing my WhatsApp images. Upon browsing them, I accidentally deleted one image that means a lot to me.

1. I've tried Dr.Fone did not really work.
2. I've heard that if I uninstall it, I'll be able to restore my data (but I am not sure, I am afraid I'll lose my data).

Comment: I tried to go back to the conversation when my friend sent to me and re-downloaded , but i got popup says "Sorry, this file doesn't exist on your SD card "

Comment: Do you have root access..

Comment: Maybe your friend has a copy of it still? Have you checked that?

Comment: Have you configured backup with google account?
If you have, there is a chance getting it back. By uninstalling and installing whatsapp. (You should also have `backup images and videos` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **ROOT  ACCESS**
Try **[Undeleter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.undelete)**

This app scans and recovers deleted files from SD cards and internal
storage.

Features:

- Restore any file that has not been written over
- Works with documents, images, video, music, archives and binaries
- Save files directly to Dropbox, Google Drive and Sdcard

If you **DONT HAVE ROOT ACCESS**

- The first thing to do is to connect the phone memory (internal or external) as a Mass Storage Device to your computer, ie, via USB.
- Then download [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) (you can use either the paid or free version), which is a program to recover files for windows.
- When you run Recuva, the first thing to do is select the type of file you want to recover: Pictures, Videos, Music, Documents, etc. and set a specific folder to attempt recovery from. *(In your case select image recovery from Sdcard/Whatsapp/Media/Whatsapp Images)*

**Other Free Data Recovery Softwares:**
* [ZAR](http://www.z-a-recovery.com/tutorials/digital-image-recovery.aspx)
*[Card Recovery](http://www.cardrecovery.com/)
*[Pc Inspecter File Recovery](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/pcinspector.html)
*[PicaJet Photo Recovery](http://m.download.cnet.com/PicaJet-Photo-Recovery/3000-2192_4-53997.html)

Comment: If you havent rooted your phone..you dont have the root access..for more info. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android_OS)

Comment: I wish I could show you a pic of the result of using   Recuva, but anyway after scanning, I got ." No  preview available" , so I think It's not a good idea using  the software . Only two pics were shown. :(

Comment: I am afraid that if you are unable to view image it may be written over...i.e it may be permanently deleted from your system..

Comment: If you wish to try again...I have listed some more data recovery softwares in edited answer ..